# How to create a server for Android app which receive and transmit data to my application without socket?

Tags: java, android, mysql, servlets

I want to create a **java server application** which receives data from an **Android client** and also transmit notification to client. Actually i did not know much about server apps. I am quite familiar with servlets and  mysql, is there any tutorials based on these??

So any suggestion how to build it or any tutorials for it?? please help me!

Comment: For a network communication a socket is necessary ;) But you can try a higher level protocoll like http or better https ;) Easest I can think of is a simple node.js express application. There you get a server that handles the network stuff by node.js and a simple rest framework express.

Comment: @rmertins http/https also based on sockets.

Comment: LOL, of course. As I sad a socket is the lowest end of a network communication between two endpoints ;)

Comment: Ok. Is there any tutorial of coding with node.js srver??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is `Google App Engine` a SaaS by Google. While there are many alternatives this is probably the best route you can take for implementing a Java based backend. Follow these tutorials* and you'll be good to go. Keep in mind the GAE is a bit complicated and will take some time to get on your feet.

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java

More tutorials on GAE can be found by a nice google search!

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much!! That is what i am lokking for. :)